# get slice of specified field from slice of structs

Tags: go, struct, slice

I have a slice of structs that contains 10 cars like:

```
type struct car {
    engine
    window
    wheel
}
```

so the slice cars contains 10 car struct.

I would like to know if a function exist such as:

```
var engines string[] = cars.Getfield("engine") // engines will contain 10 engines names
```

Comment: This does not exist, you'll need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no library function for this.

You can implement manually using [reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package

Example:

```
type Cars []Car

func (cars Cars) getFieldString(field string) []string {
    var data []string
    for _, car := range cars {
        r := reflect.ValueOf(car)
        f := reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName(field)
        data = append(data, f.String())
    }
    return data
}
```

Code in Playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/LJqMDi3-pcs)

Answer (score 0):

There's no generics in Go (not until 2.0 at least), so there's not a lot of helper functions out there.

If you need to use this function often, you can implement it as a method for type `engines`.

Comment: 11/2022, generics are available; I would like to know how generics would solve this problem...

Answer (score -1):

Answering [@RodolfoAP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9911256/rodolfoap) question under [@Joe-Akanesuvan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10369507/joe-akanesuvan) answer (not enough rep to post as a comment):
Even though generics are a part of Go now, there're no functional programming libs in std, I used [1st one I found](https://github.com/repeale/fp-go) on `awesome-go`, so this is probably isn't production-ready code, but that's generally what it would look like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    fp "github.com/repeale/fp-go"
)

type data struct {
    field        string
    anotherField int
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf(
        "result: %+v",
        fp.Map(func(d data) string { return d.field })(
            []data{
                {
                    field:        "apple",
                    anotherField: 1,
                },
                {
                    field:        "orange",
                    anotherField: 2,
                },
                {
                    field:        "banana",
                    anotherField: 3,
                },
            },
        ),
    )
}
```

Code output:

```
result: [apple orange banana]
```

Code in playground [here](https://go.dev/play/p/-TvSbKX4uP9)